# Connecting to CloudSql via psycopg2

Tags: psycopg2, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect to CloudSQL on GCP using pycopg2

In order to do this I use as host:

```
'my-project-dev-a24525:europe-west1:sql-dev-432521ec-master'
```

as given in "Instance connection name"

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host='my-project-dev-a24525:europe-west1:sql-dev-432521ec-master',
database="postgres", user="admin", password="password")
```

However this results in:

could not translate host name "my-project-dev-a24525:europe-west1:sql-dev-432521ec-master" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

If I connect via the public ip address as in

conn = psycopg2.connect(host='xx.xxx.xx.xxx', database="postgres", user="admin", password="password")

the connection is fine.

Where can I find the proper hostname in GCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Cloud SQL instance doesn't have a DNS name associated with it (unless you give it one).

The "instance connection name" which you have listed can be used to connect with the [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) or when interacting with the [Cloud SQL Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/), but doesn't have any DNS significance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add '/cloudsql/' to your instance connection name, so just replace

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host='my-project-dev-a24525:europe-west1:sql-dev-432521ec-master',database="postgres", user="admin", password="password")
```

with

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host='/cloudsql/my-project-dev-a24525:europe-west1:sql-dev-432521ec-master',
```

database="postgres", user="admin", password="password")

Comment: This assumes you are running the [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy) via Unix sockets either by deploying it locally or using a Google Cloud application that deploys it for you (adding a "Cloud SQL Connection" to Cloud Run etc.). Might be worth pointing this out in your answer :)